# Наследование в Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Как реализовать наследование через синтаксис vm ?

Пример кода, где обычное наследование через $scope:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="scope">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Scope</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  {{vm.test}} <!-- переменная из MainController -->
  <div ng-controller="SecondController as vm">
  {{test}} <!-- переменная из MainController -->
  {{vm.test}} <!-- пусто тк SecondController vm пустой обьект, но через наследование он должен лезть в MainController -->
  <main-dir></main-dir>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('scope', []);

  angular
    .module('scope')
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.test = '1';

      var vm = this;
      vm.test = '1';
    }])
    .controller('SecondController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      // тут по сути должен быть прототип на родителя MainController, и собственно в прототипе должно быть свойство test
      var vm = this;
    }])
    .directive('mainDir', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div>{{test}}</div>',
        link: function ($scope, el, attr) {
           // как тут получить vm.test или нужно использовать controller вместо link
        }
      }
    })
})();
```

Comment: `controller as` синтаксис как раз и добавили чтобы уйти от наследования повсеместного

Comment: Вынеси декларацию объекта в сервис который создаёт сингелтон при инициализации программы, и инжекть его в контролеры

Comment: @Den, больше сервисов богу сервисов :-D

Comment: мда походу ещё не проснулся, не так вопрос понял ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `controller as` синтаксис как раз и добавили чтобы уйти от наследования повсеместного.
   И в вашем случае наследование не нужно, достаточно просто дать осмысленные имена контроллерам:

   ```
   <body ng-controller="MainController as mc_vm">
       {{mc_vm.test}} <!-- переменная из MainController -->
       <div ng-controller="SecondController as sc_vm">
           {{mc_vm.test}} <!-- переменная из MainController -->
           {{sc_vm.test}} <!-- пусто тк SecondController vm пустой обьект, но через наследование он должен лезть в MainController -->
   ```
2. В случае с директивой - вариантов куча: от получения через атрибуты, до получения из scope, так как, когда пишется `MainController as mc_vm` в скоп контроллера добавляется свойство `mc_vm`.
   [Справка по директивам](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Тогда какой подход использовать ? Гуру пишут что нужно через vm, но тогда нельзя использовать наследование, приходится писать что то вроде $scope.$parent.$parent.vm.какая то переменная и родителя второго уровня, с использование $scope я просто пишу $scope.переменная и angular идет по цепочке наследования пока не найдет переменную.

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, все зависит от **конкретной** задачи, кроме того, при использовании контроллеров стараются избегать использование `$scope` вообще, поэтому и ситуации `$scope.$parent.$parent...` быть не может

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, если у вас проблема с `$scope.$parent.$parent...` подготовьте пример и задайте отдельным вопросом

Comment: Ну вот тот же код, я в SecondController хочу получить переменную test через наследования, чтобы мне не приходилось писать vm.test = $scope.$parent.vm.test, я так понял если я хочу так делать, то синтаксис vm не для меня

Comment: К примеру в той же директиве есть функции link и controller в которые передаются $scope, и если контроллеры работают через $scope, то я так же указываю $scope.test и ангуляр идет по цепочке, если же через vm, то в директиве тоже не будет наследования, я тупо иду по цепочке ($scope.$parent.$parent.vm.test) и ищу переменную

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy, просто вы делаете это не правильно. Сформулируйте  и задайте отдельным вопросом. Так как к текущей теме. наследование, это не имеет никакого отношения. Здесь просто передача данных в директиву.

Comment: Как получить test в директиве функии link, которая указа в коде из контроллера MainController, притом не передавая test как атрибут

Comment: @KhoteyVitaliy 1. Это стоит задать отдельным вопросом. а не комментарием. 2. в приведенной в ответе ссылке приведены способы передачи данных в директиву

Answer (score 1):

При использовании синтаксиса `controller as` нужно использовать javascript прототипы.

```
function MainController() {
    this.view = MainController.prototype.view;
}

MainController.prototype.view = { test: 'test' };

function SecondController() {
    MainController.prototype.view.test = 'test2';
}
```

Можно почитать тут http://rav.pw/angularjs-inheritance/